# How can I get the index of a specific node in a doubly linked list?

Tags: java, function, doubly-linked-list, deque, sentinel

I have a class called `SLList` whuch accepts a doubly linked list `SLList` of any generic type as an input.

I've decided to use a sentinel approach to aid in my task.

I am now trying to convert my doubly linked list into a string using function `public String makestring()` and also get the index of a specific node via function `public T findindexof(int i)`

Here is my code so far:

```
public class SLList<T>{ 
        private class IntNode {
        private T data;
        private IntNode previous;
        private IntNode next;

        public IntNode (T data, IntNode previous, IntNode next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.previous = previous;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public IntNode () { 
            next = previous = this;
        }
    }

    IntNode sentinel; 
    private int length = 0;

    public SLList(){
        sentinel = new IntNode(); // Self referencing previous/next
    }

    
    public String makestring() {
        return sentinel.data.toString();
    }
    public T findindexof(int i) {
        return sentinel.data[i];
    }
```

My `findindexof(int i)` must only get the item at the given index, where 0 is the front, 1 is the next item and so forth. If no such item exists, returns null. It must not alter the deque either.

I am struggling to understand how to implement this function, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop for `i` iterations, moving between nodes through the `next` field each time.

```java
public T findindexof(int i) {
    IntNode curr = sentinel;
    for (int j = 0; j < i && curr != null; j++)
        curr = curr.next;
    return curr != null ? curr.data : null;
}
```

Comment: one more thing which may not be concerned with this, can you please have a look at my makestring() method and see if I did it right or not? you don't have to provide a solution, I just want to know if I'm right or wrong

Comment: @Nutnicha What is that method supposed to do? You are currently returning only the data for the first node.

Comment: its supposed to turn the doubly linked list into a string

Comment: @Nutnicha You should loop over the entire list until you hit null then and append the data of each node into a string (or `StringBuilder`).

Comment: shouldn't findIndexOf return the index?

Comment: @ChengThao The method isn't named well. It is actually more like `getAtIndex`.